# Snow Leopard - otool: command not found (?)

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard

Trying to use otool -L in place of ldd, but it says it can't be found... As root, even running a locate otools in terminal shows nothing... Is it not on Snow Leopard? Does anyone know where it is?

Comment: You need to install the developer tools to get access to otool. Once you've installed the developer tools (must check UNIX/system tools) it will be at /usr/bin/otool as well as /Developer/usr/bin/otool (or whatever place you installed the tools)

Comment: Also, these kinds of questions really belong on superuser.stackoverflow.com since they're more related to 'how do I set up my system' than 'how do I program such&such' or 'how do I achieve such and such result' etc.

Comment: @Jason: Seems to me that [otool](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/otool.1.html) is pretty clearly a "software tool commonly used by programmers", which makes it [on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) here.

Comment: @Cody Gray: I'd say it's one of those gray areas... yes, it's definitely a dev tool, but he's not asking about how to use it or even how to make it work right, he's asking where to find it and how to install it, which is more setup/superuser IMHO, but that's just my opinion anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the Apple Developer Tools to make `otool` available. You can register to download them [here](http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/mac/index.action) for free (no need to become a "Mac Developer Program" member).

After you've installed the Developer Tools, `otool` is in `/usr/bin` (which is usually in your `$PATH`).

<sup>No need to upvote this post: I just repeated information already in the comments.</sup>

Comment: Any way to get otool without downloading over a gig of other stuff that I don't need?

Answer (score 0):

/Developer/usr/bin/otool is one place it's usually found.
Also see /usr/bin/otool